# How to know if a Firestore document is either remote or local in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to build a confirmation check for my opensource Flutter Chat App,
to show whether a message has been saved in the database or not

**message not saved in Firestore yet:**

[image]

**message saved in Firestore**

[image]

The listener:

```
final receivingMessagesStream = firestore
        .collection("conversations")
        .doc(conversationId)
        .collection("messages")
        .snapshots()
```

To make it work, I created a cloud function that adds a `sentAt` field to the message document once its created, so `receivingMessagesStream` receives a new version of the message with `sentAt != null` so it shows the check

The cloud function:

```
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import {onDocumentCreated} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

exports.sentAtTrigger = onDocumentCreated("conversations/{conversationId}/messages/{messageId}", async (event) => {
    logger.log(`new message created: ${event.data!.id}`);
    await event.data!.ref.update({
        sentAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
});
```

Is there another solution to know whether a document is only in user's local device or if is remotely? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes).

You can either:

1. Check the Future has completed successfully for the document write
2. Pass `includeMetadataChanges: true` to [snapshots()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) and check the [hasPendingWrites](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/SnapshotMetadata/hasPendingWrites.html) property of the DocumentSnapshot metadata that you want to ensure has been written to the server.